# The first city that **put** into effect ... Why *put* instead of *puts*?

Tags: past-tense, verb-forms, irregular-forms

> The first city in the United States that put into effect major plans
>   for the clustering of government buildings was Washington.

I think the word "put" should be added "s" because of the first city. I think it's a singular noun, but the solution says that there is no need

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having no "s" makes it sound correct in the past tense. The addition of an "s" makes the start sound almost like a competition. "The first city that puts into effect  will win...etc".

That being said, I find it slightly difficult to read the sentence in its current structure.

"The first city in the United States that put major plans for the clustering of government buildings into effect was Washington."

That way flows much more naturally for me.

Comment: I find it rather odd that you find your version easier to parse. To me it's a clunky sentence in the first place, but splicing so many words inside the ["phrasal verb"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8kfvotMI5hYC&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=phrasal+verb+%22put+into+effect%22&source=bl&ots=f4TQ6fGqlo&sig=0rdjBLyx3P-AgAvZWcIrTEU_FzI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDQQ6AEwA2oVChMIx7aKmauXxwIVS7sUCh3t5g0z#v=onepage&q=phrasal%20verb%20%22put%20into%20effect%22&f=false) ***put into effect*** has the precise opposite effect for me.

Answer (score 4):

"The first city in the United States that **put** into effect major plans for the clustering of government buildings **was** Washington."

The sentence is in the past tense; hence, it is sound that both verbs are in the [**past**](http://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/put) form.

Comment: Please, don't just paste a link, but also copy the text from the part of the page pertaining to your answer, and use a ">" to paste that into a quote box.